# iPhone: how to test if UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is working?

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I set the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to boolean and checked the checkbox, so I assumed that

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

is not called - but I always get into that method when I click the home button in my simulator. Am I doing something wrong or can I be sure that the app will behave the "old style" and does not support multitasking?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

**Settings defined at this level**
Architectures: Standard
Base SDK: iPhone Simulator 4.0
Code Signing Identity: iPhone Developer: myName
Any iPhone OS Device: iPhone Developer: myName
iPhone OS Deployment Target: iPhone OS 3.1
Other Linker Flags: -lxml2
Prebinding: not selected
Header search paths: /usr/include/libxml2
C language dialect: C99 [-std=99] 
Mismatched Return Type: selected
Unused variables: selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One difference I have found to test this is using the iPhone 4 Simulator or Device connected to the Xcode debugger.  If you have it enabled properly, when you hit the home button it will exit the debugger.  If "multitasking" is enabled, when you hit the home button, the debugger will not exit - touching your icon and bringing it back will continue with your debugging session.

Comment: hm... I'm using Device "iPhone 4" but debugger is ALWAYS exited, no matter how I configured the property. Base SDK "iPhone Simulator 4.0" and "iPhone OS Deployment Target" "Compiler Default" (there is no version 4, the highest is 3.2). Am I missing something?

Comment: Something doesn't sound right - you've got Xcode 3.2.3?  I set my Base SDK to "iPhone Device 4.0" and the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to "iPhone OS 3.1".  Where is there no "version 4"?

Comment: I also set Base SDK to "iPhone Device 4.0" and "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to "iPhone OS 3.1". In my simulator, I always get "Debugger stopped. Program exited with status value:0." when clicking on the home button... "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" with boolean type, checkbox selected.

Comment: If you are using the iPhone 4 simulator and you uncheck this box it should "suspend" (if not, try removing the property entirely and/or cleaning all targets and rebuilding).  If you're using the iPhone 3.2 simulator, it will always exit as this property is iOS 4 only.

Comment: I just don't get it... my "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" is completely ignored... when I ask for "[device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]" => on Simulator 4.0 it's always true, on 3.2 it's always false. But I really need to be sure that multitasking is turned off... I don't know if I can trust the plist-parameter, when I cant test it without 3GS :(

Comment: I think that is to be expected; iOS 4 will always respond true, 3.2 false.  The behavior on "exit" is what changes based on the property setting.  I wish I could help more - for me, setting the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend property to YES exits the debugger, removing the property does not.  The only time it didn't work was when I had a typo - UIApplicationExistsOnSuspend...  :)

Comment: can you give me one more hint? did you configure something different than I did - comparing my configuration above? thanks a lot, really...

Comment: Settings look generally the same, I'm not using libxml, but that won't matter.  

Changing the Active Executable to "YourApp - iPhone Simulator 4.0" should follow the Info.plist property value.  Try doing a "clean all targets" and then compiling+running from scratch.  Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

A must read for that problem with a FLowChart what happens when on iOS4

Answer (score 2):

Setting YES to UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend , worked well for me from the first time,But i didn realize,as my app was shown when double-clicking.

"double-clicking on the home button will always show your app , as it is a list of recently used apps. ( Ref: http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/multitasking.html ) "

If applicationWillTerminate delegate method is called, then you are done with that.. (Add a break point or NSLog to check )

Just a tip. Hope this helps some one like me..;)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it wasn't working because the app was still listed in the multi-tasking manager. After testing it though I was able to see in the console that the app really is completely restarting instead of just coming out of the background.

Answer (score 0):

The key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend works fine only on device iPhone 4.
It doesn't work on iPhone 3GS even if you installed iOS4 and have multitasking.
That's what our tests show.

Comment: No...It's working in my case for other apps. But not for my app.

Answer (score 0):

During my tests `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called (and afterwards `ApplicationWillTerminate`), although I've set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES`, too. I've tested the app on an iPhone 3G with iOS 4.1 installed and in the iPhone 4 Simulator.

Has somebode tested this on an iPhone 4?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me is converting my info.plist file to xml. I created a new blank project just to see the info.plist file and saw that it was in xml, whereas my older project did not have info.plist in xml format. So, I used the new info.plist xml format to rewrite my info.plist file. After doing that, the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key now works and my app terminates