# Disabling multitasking on iPhone 3GS using UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend not working

Tags: iphone, multitasking, iphone-3gs

I am developing an iPhone app where I don’t want/need the multitasking capability and I want my app to initiate every time I open it.
I have set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` property in the **info.plist** and it does work when I test it on my iPhone 4 and in the simulator (which is also an ”iPhone 4”). The app calls `applicationDidEnterBackground` followed by `applicationWillTerminate`. However, when testing it on my wifes iPhone 3GS the property seems to be completely ignored and the program gets suspended/resumed. Both phones are running iOS 4.2.1.

Someone has also confirmed this issue in another thread, with no solutions unfortunately:
[iPhone: how to test if UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188076/iphone-how-to-test-if-uiapplicationexitsonsuspend-is-working)

Is there something I am missing to make this work? Any other ways to accomplish this?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Try uninstalling from the iPhone 3GS, performing a clean, then rebuilding and reinstalling.

Comment: Is your application linked against iOS 4.x? (Base SDK)

Comment: @BoltClock: Will try this when I get home from work. I'm not holding my breath though :)

Comment: @Saurabh: Yes, I have checked this. It is building against the newest SDK (4.2.something I think).

Comment: call `exit(0)` in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there doesn't seem to be an viable solution to this problem, neither here or in the Apple Developer forum.
I just gave up and implemented the multitasking capability to at least get consistent behaviour across the different iPhone models.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the application is meant for iPhone 4 and not iPhone 3GS

You can upgrade your iPhone to iPhone 4 by paying a little amount.'

And also try running the app on another persons iPhone (4) to make sure that the application works fine

Comment: Upgrading my phone is not a solution because I am not making the application for my self but for the App Store and I obviously want it to run correctly on people’s 3GS. And the documentation about the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend property only says that you must run iOS 4.0 or newer, says nothing about it not being available for the 3GS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Application does not run in background` key in the info.plist file and make sure it is checked.

Comment: The UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend IS the "Application does not run in background" key. The whole issue is that it doesn't seem to woerk on 3GS.